# Multiple Associations With the Same Table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two class User and Bug there are two foreign keys in bug which are referencing to user_id ..the problem is that how i store user_id in foreign key column while creating the record.like for example if user enter bug then his id store in buger_id colunm.

class Bug

```
belongs_to :buger, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "buger_id"
belongs_to :developer , class_name: "User", foreign_key: "developer_id"
```

class user

```
has_many :created_bugs, class_name:"bugs"
has_many :developed_bugs, class_name:"bugs"
```

Comment: maybe better to call that `reporter` or `creator`  instead of `buger`? :)

Comment: ok i change it i am getting this error,,, undefined local variable or method `creator' for

Comment: thanks my problem solve

Comment: can you up-vote my answer and check it as correct?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the foreign_key to the has_many declaration!

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :created_bugs, class_name: 'Bug'   , foreign_key: :buger_id
    has_many :developed_bugs, class_name: 'Bug' , foreign_key: :developer_id
  end

  class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :buger, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :developer , class_name: 'User'
  end
```

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specify class and foreign key on the has_many line as well.

```
has_many :created_bugs, class_name:"Bug", foreign_key: 'buger_id'
has_many :developed_bugs, class_name:"Bug", foreign_key: 'developer_id'
```

Comment: I update my question and also define has_many like u said but sitll i dont how create command work in this case.{@bug = buger.created_bugs.create(bug_params)} this line is giving me error undefined local variable or method `buger'

Comment: @bug = Bug.new ... buger is a method of an existing Bug and points to a buger, it can't be used without a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5.1 or greater you can do it like this:

### Migration

```
class CreateBug < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    ccreate_table(:bugs) do |t|
        t.references :bugger, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }
        t.references :developer, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }
    end
  end
end
```

This will create the fields `bugger_id`, and `developer_id` and make the database level references to the `users` table

### Models

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bugger, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :developer, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_bugs, class_name: "Bug", foreign_key: "bugger_id"
  has_many :developed_bugs, class_name: "Bug", foreign_key: "developer_id"
end
```

### FactoryBot

If you use FactoryBot then your factory might look something like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :bug do
    association :bugger, factory: :user
    association :developer, factory: :user
  end
end
```