# How can i self reference user in another table ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activeadmin

Hi i need to have a manager for my user table. I have now created an intermediate table called liaison which will contain manager_id and references user_id table. The problem is that i don't know how to add the association between them and i need to list the users as manager in my activeadmin panel also during user creation.

I have tried this association in user.rb

```
  has_many :liaisons
  has_many :managers, through: :liaisons
```

In liaison.rb

```
  has_many :users
  has_many :users, through: :liaisons
```

My liaisons table contains manager_id and user_id i need to create multiple managers for a single user.

I need to list the all the users as managers during creation of user and associate them. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can look into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104085/multiple-associations-with-the-same-table-rails similar issue but with Bugs and Developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The liaisons model only references a single user/manager and needs to know to map managers back to the users table:

```rb
class Liaison < ApplicationModel
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If each user only has one manager then it would be easier to do away with the `"Liaison"` model entirely, and just have a `manager_id` column in `users`.  Then in the `User` model you could have:

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User',
                     inverse_of: :direct_reports, optional: true
has_many :direct_reports, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :manager_id,
                          inverse_of: :manager
```

Example of this setup can be seen in this project:
https://github.com/lorint/Simpsons

And a bit more description about this manager_id association is demonstrated starting at 1:30 in this video:

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/13rml5y/video_response_to_gmfts_question_about_hmt/

(Other stuff being demo'd as well, but you can see the ERD diagram and 65 users in a hierarchy.)